# The problem with box at the end of example

Tags: examples

I have to be at the end of each example, sign the box. However, in various situations, it appears in some other places. I would like that it was always in the same place. I wish that was on the right side in the last line. As in the first example. I do not want to was lower as in the example of the second and third. When the example ends the text is well. However, when the ends using array or equation is below. I do not know how to change it. It is very important to me.

[image]
It is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{indentfirst}  
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{url}

\textwidth 15.3cm 
\textheight 22.2cm 
\topmargin 0cm 
\oddsidemargin 0.55cm 
\evensidemargin 0cm 

\fancypagestyle{number}{
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\newtheoremstyle{stylexample}% name
  {}%      Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%      Space below
  {\normalfont}% Body font e.g. \normalfont \bfseries \itshape
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec


\theoremstyle{stylzad}
\newtheorem{example}[chapter]{Example}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\null\hfill\qedsymbol}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{number}\chapter{Number}

\begin{example}
During the 19th century, mathematicians began to develop many different abstractions which share certain properties of numbers and may be seen as extending the concept. Among the first were the hypercomplex numbers, which consist of various extensions or modifications of the complex number system. Today, number systems are considered important special examples of much more general categories such as rings and fields, and the application of the term "number" is a matter of convention, without fundamental significance.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
$$
\begin{array}{c}
abc:\\
a  \\
b \\
c .\\
\end{array}$$\end{example}

\begin{example}
\begin{equation} \nonumber
2+3=5
\end{equation}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\qedhere`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). By the way, you can have a look there to know more about [*minimal* working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) `(-;`

Comment: Using `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm`, this would be automatic. Comment aside; don't use `$$…$$`, which plain TeX code for displayed equations. Replace it with `\[ … \]`.

Comment: That is how it is when you use amsthm, you could switch to ntheorem, and use its thmmarks option, then it can place it like you want. There is a price to pay of course, no blank lines before end example, plus it may take a few compilations before the marker settles

Comment: I add \qedhere but i don't see box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is to use `\qedhere` at the end of the last line of math, before you close any environment such as `array` or `align`.

```
\begin{example}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
abc:\\
a   \\
b   \\
c. \qedhere % <-- here
\end{array}
\]
\end{example}
```